# Finding lines between several points

Tags: c#, image-processing, line, emgucv, aforge

I'm programming to make a image processing application using C#.NET (Windows Forms), EmguCV 3.1 (OpenCV wrapper for C#) and AForgeNet(another library for image processing). I extract several key points from an image as depicted below:

[image]

As it can be seen, there are several white points and red lines. White points shows location of key points? I want to extract lines for each group of pixels having this properties:
**1-** distance among pixels must be almost equal.
**2-** they must be close together.

Is there any method or approach to extract lines between pixels among aforementioned libraries?  An example of lines that I imagine is depicted in the figure.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to find lines in points.  Ransac is probably the best.  Once you find lines in your points, find the points that lie on the line, and test to see that they are roughly equally spaced.

Alternatively, look at all the inter point distances, cluster those distances, and see if any of those clusters live on lines (fit lines using robust techniques, or ransac, the better choice will depend on how noisy these sets are)